# how can we change text color in blender with using of python

Tags: python, blender

```
mat_red = bpy.data.materials.new("Text")
mat_red.diffuse_color = (0.85, 0.8, 1,1)
mesh = bpy.context.object.data
mesh.materials.append(mat_red)
```

not changing the color of text.

Answer (score 2):

While you are adding a material to the object, the material will only be used if no other material already exists on the object. You can check the length of the material list to see if you want to append a new material or replace the existing material with your new one.

```
mat_red = bpy.data.materials.new("Text")
mat_red.diffuse_color = (0.85, 0.8, 1.1)
mesh = bpy.context.object.data

if len(mesh.materials) == 0:
    mesh.materials.append(mat_red)
else:
    mesh.materials[0] = mat_red
```

You could check the length first and adjust the existing material, then only create a new one when needed.